# The split method is not working - want to split the date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, split

I'm trying to split the date on both release_*date and first_air*_date however the split() method isn't working for me. What am I doing wrong - please explain! I'm a beginner. Many thanks in advance!

Below is my code:

```
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import React from "react";

function Card({ daily }) {
    let text = daily.release_date;
    let airDate = daily.first_air_date;
    
    const myArray = text.split("-");
    const splitDate = airDate.split("-");
    const word = myArray[0]; 
    const date = splitDate[0];
    console.log(word);
    console.log(date);

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                width: "25%",
                height: "550px",
                backgroundColor: "#144272",
                alignSelf: "flex-start",
                borderRadius: "10px",
            }}
        >
            <Box
                sx={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "85%",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="img-src"
                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${daily.poster_path}`}
                    alt=""
                    style={{
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%",
                        objectFit: "cover",
                        borderRadius: "20px",
                    }}
                />
            </Box>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    align: "center",
                    fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    color: "#fff",
                    margin: "5px 10px",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                }}
            >
                {daily.original_title ? (
                    <Typography sx={{}}>{daily.original_title}</Typography>
                ) : (
                    <Typography sx={{}}>{daily.name}</Typography>
                )}
                <Typography
                    sx={{
                        fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
                        fontWeight: "lighter",
                        fontSize: "15px",
                        color: "#fff",
                        margin: "5px 10px",
                    }}
                >
                    {/*word*/}
                </Typography>
                
                {daily.release_date ? (
                    <Typography sx={{}}>{text}</Typography>
                ) : (
                    <Typography sx={{}}>{/*airDate*/}</Typography>
                )}
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

I used the split() method in another component, here is the code for that one and it worked fine:

```
import React from "react";

function Card({ recomendations }) {
    let text = recomendations.release_date;

    const myArray = text.split("-");
    let word = myArray[0];
    console.log(word);
    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                width: "25%",
                height: "550px",
                backgroundColor: "#144272",
                alignSelf: "flex-start",
                borderRadius: "10px",
            }}
        >
            <Box
                sx={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "85%",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="img-src"
                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${recomendations.poster_path}`}
                    alt=""
                    style={{
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%",
                        objectFit: "cover",
                        borderRadius: "20px",
                    }}
                />
            </Box>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    align: "center",
                    fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    color: "#fff",
                    margin: "5px 10px",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                }}
            >
                <Typography sx={{}}>{recomendations.original_title}</Typography>
                <Typography
                    sx={{
                        fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
                        fontWeight: "lighter",
                        fontSize: "15px",
                        color: "#fff",
                        margin: "5px 10px",
                    }}
                >
                    {word}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: if the data type of `.release_date` is actually a Date object, you'll need to use `.release_date.toJSON().split(-)`

Comment: @RandyCasburn tried but it still doesn't work console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: then `.release_date` does not exist on the `daily` object. You'll need to correct that or test for it first. `const text = daily?.release_date || '';` or something similar.